# @Page blank header for certain pages

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to format a web page to make it friendly. On the first page I want a blank header. On the rest of the pages I want text in the header. I came across this article from 2005 [Printing a Book](https://alistapart.com/article/boom/) and I am having a hard time following the examples.

I wrote some code. It works except for the page headers.

```css
@page {
  size: 7in 9.25in;
  margin: 27mm 16mm 27mm 16mm;
}

div.titlepage,
div.chapter,
div.appendix {
  page-break-after: always;
}

div.titlepage {
  page: blank;
}

@page :left {
  @top-left {
    content: "Here is a story";
  }
}

@page blank :left {
  @top-left {
    content: normal;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="titlepage">
  <h1>Title Page</h1>
</div>
<div class="chapter">
  <h1 style="color:red">Chapter 1</h1>
  <p>
    Text goes here
  </p>
</div>
<div class="chapter">
  <h1 style="color:blue">Chapter 2</h1>
  <p>
    More text goes here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what's *not* working from your example. On the main page, just don't include text in the header? `<h1></h1>`

Comment: Does this have to work in all browsers?  @page  rules aren't well supported at the moment.

Comment: @wahwahwah When you print out the example. On the first page, you should just see Title Page. On the next pages in the top left you should see the words "This is a story". So in my code, if a page is named blank you should not see a header else you will see the words "This is a story"

Comment: @MikeBrockington I am using IE 11.